# I can't save images on IOS but it works perfectly fine on Android (Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to fetch images from a website and saving it on the mobile phone. It works fine on Android but as soon as I try it on IOS I am not able to download the images and I am not able to save them.

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = '/Users/benni/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4F5653A9-221B-4346-B3F0-DECF56309E9A/data/Containers/Data/Application/E8D7F059-5D40-4BED-ACAC-79FF451A4DA7/Documents/carImages/968050475/mainImage.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _File.open.<anonymous closure> (dart:io/file_impl.dart:366:9)
(elided 13 frames from dart:async)
Path: /Users/benni/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4F5653A9-221B-4346-B3F0-DECF56309E9A/data/Containers/Data/Application/E8D7F059-5D40-4BED-ACAC-79FF451A4DA7/Documents/carImages/968050475/mainImage.jpg
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I am creating the folder with the following code:

```dart
      Future<void> _createDirectory() async {
    final String path = await _localPath;
    documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final Directory directory =
        await Directory('$path/carImages').create(recursive: true);
  }
```

I am fetching the images with the following code:

```dart
    Future<void> downloadImagesForCar(List<dynamic> urlList, String firstPath,
      String urlFirstImage, Car car) async {
    //----------------------IMAGE GET
    try {
      String firstImagePath =
          firstPath + "/mainImage.jpg"; // only for first image
      if (!await File(firstImagePath).exists()) {
        get(urlFirstImage + "/webp/420")
            .then((response) => {writeImageFile(response, firstImagePath)});
        //  .catchError(() => {car.mainImageExists = false});
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
        String filePathAndName = firstPath + "/$i.jpg";

        if (!await File(filePathAndName).exists()) {
          get(urlList[i].toString() + "/webp/420").then(
                  (response) => {writeImageFile(response, filePathAndName)})
              // .catchError(handleImageDownloadError())
              ;
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
 
    }
  }
```

I am handling the image with the following code:

```dart
     void writeImageFile(var response, String filePathAndName) {
    File imageFile = new File(filePathAndName);

    imageFile.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes); // <-- 3
    imagePaths.add(filePathAndName);
  }
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5965747-data-persistence-on-flutter Does it help?

Comment: Not really but thanks.